# Akka HTTPS how to support TLS1.2

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have created simple Akka HTTP server that listen on HTTPS
i saw that by default it use TLSv1 which is old and deprecated
how can i remove it and use proper TLS version and normal ciphers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")` with `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2")`.